# How do I add image to this canvas ball?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, dom-events

I am trying to make a simple game, though if I need an image for my bouncing ball then how do I do this?
I am doing this-

```
function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 300);
    if (ctx.getContext) {

            Snooker = new Image();
            Snooker.onload = loadingComplete;
            Snooker.src = "http://www.wpclipart.com/toys/balls/red_snooker_ball.png";
        }
    x += dx;
    y += dy;
    bounce();
}
```

**And->**

```
function init() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas");

    return setInterval(draw, 10);
}
```

Now canvas is blank.

**Here is fiddle link-**
http://jsfiddle.net/stackmanoz/QcLTw/1/

Image I want to add instead of this simple ball-
http://www.wpclipart.com/toys/balls/red_snooker_ball.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working version of your script using the image instead of the `arc`. You would want to load an img using Javascript's `new Image()` and then set the source to the image you want. Then use `drawImage` instead of `arc`.

http://jsfiddle.net/QcLTw/7/

Comment: check fiddle now, ball has image but it's fixed to an angle. I want ball moving by all angles. How can you do this?

Comment: Rotating the image will require separate code to accomplish. You can refer to [here](http://creativejs.com/2012/01/day-10-drawing-rotated-images-into-canvas/) for an example of how to rotate an image on the canvas.